# Firefox: very slow download of 9th request

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, firefox

In my example.localhost I have lots of requests for css and js files (during development). For some reason, if there are 9 of them, the last one crawls.

Ie: first connection is to fetch html itself, then 3 css and 5 javascript files. If you check the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AHv3.jpg) you will see that last one takes a lot of time to load.

Even if I change the order of files, no changes, the last one will take much more time than the rest.

Note:
this problem does not appear in Chrome but I have to use firebug.

Comment: Is it possible you're hitting the maximum number of concurrent connections? See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections-per-server and try changing your `network.http.max-connections-per-server` setting in `about:config` and see if that helps?

Comment: I didn't even had that option so I added it and no changes. For some reason, FF marked it as string, not integer.

Comment: @Zeljko If you added the pref yourself and it turned into a string, you did something wrong. Was the value you typed a whole number? When you use something else than digits, even a space, it will get turned into a string. Reset the pref and try again.

Comment: I typed 12 and now browser tells me it is a string. I can't even delete it any more and retry in case I missclicked. Now I have 2 problems :)